# Get rid of decimal place and cancel out comma

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a data like this:

```
cat file
(4567.99,5678.98)
(5678.33,6734.34)
```

The output I want is:

```
(45679900 56789800)
(56783300 67343400)
```

I want to cancel out the decimal and let it become 8 digit and delete the comma sign and let it be spacing between each others.

Using `awk` command, how to do it? `sed` is also ok.

Comment: Did you take into account that some numbers might be of a different length?

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
awk -F'[(),]' '{ printf( "(%d %d)\n", $2 * 10000, $3 * 10000 ); }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed -e 's/,/ /' -e 's/\.\(..\)/\100/g'`

Answer (score 1):

TXR [awk macro](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000264BC): we can actually do this as typed operations: get the data as floating-point values, floor them down to nearest integer, multiply by a hundred, convert to integer.

> However, let us pause for a moment and reflect that this may be a bad idea if the values are so large that they cannot be truncated to the nearest integer; doing this text-wise will be correct for arbitrarily large values.

```
$ txr -e '(awk (:begin (set ft #/\d+.\d+/))
               ((mf tofloat floor toint (* 100))))'
(4567.99, 123.45, junk 3.1415, 1.0 ...) x
456700 12300 300 100
```

The `ft` variable is a new feature; classic Awk has no equivalent. Whereas `fs` is like `FS` (field separator), `ft` means "field tokenize": it specifies a positive regex which recognizes and extracts fields, ignoring non-matching stuff in between.

> Ironically `ft` can directly express the semantics of the default field separator in Awk: trimming leading and trailing newlines and blanks from the record and separating on one or more newlines or blanks. That is precisely equivalent to simply **positively** recognizing the fields as tokens consisting of non-blanks! If Awk had an `FT` variable, it wouldn't need the special hack which applies when `FS` is equal to a single space; the default could be that `FS` is not set, and `FK` is set to the regex `[ \t\n]+`.

We use a simple `ft` which recognizes digits, a mandatory decimal and mandatory digits. No leading sign, no optional parts.

The `mf` macro ("map fields") puts each field through a pipeline of operations. Firstly the `tofloat` function converts the strings to floating-point. Then `floor` truncates to the nearest integer, toward negative infinity. `toint` takes us back to inger and `(* 100)` denotes the partial application of `*` to `100`: a function which takes additional arguments and multiplies `100` by their product.  This partial application syntax follows from the fact that `mf` arguments are implicitly treated as `op` syntax: the TXR Lisp explicit partial application operator.

Since `mf` returns a non-`nil` result, the default action `(prn)` kicks in to print the updated `rec`, which is re-constituted by catenating the updated fields with the default `ofs` consisting of one space character, and outputting an `ors` which defaults to newline.

Here is a way to do it numerically, yet without relying on floating-point math. Basically we can extract the fields using the same regular expression, but then remove the dot while they are still text. Then go to integer and use truncating integer division and multiplication:

```
 $ txr -e '(awk (:begin (set ft #/\d+.\d+/))
                ((mf (remq #\.) toint (trunc @1 100) (* 100))))'
```

Since integers can be arbitrarily large in this language, this solution doesn't suffer from problems due to the numbers being large, yet minimizes the text processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{gsub(/\./,"")sub(/,/," "); print $1"00",$2}' file
(45679900 567898)
(56783300 673434)
```